# Using ant-design vanilla js and simple icons parcel

Tags: javascript, parceljs

I'm using the ant-design and simple icons for my vanilla js app. I'm facing with huge imports after I build my app. Currently 3.92mb in minified version. Is there anything I can fix this? I'm using parcel to build my website.

Build:

[image: Build]

Package.json

[image: Package]

It seems that ant-design and simple icons imports all the icons in the index.js

index.js

[image]

[image]

This is how I imports the icons:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can tell parcel generate an analysis of what is in your bundle by adding `--reporter @parcel/reporter-bundle-analyzer` to your `parcel build` command, which will output an html file with the analysis to the `parcel-bundle-reports` folder (see [docs](https://parceljs.org/features/production/#analyzing-bundle-sizes)). That analysis will at least tell you what is the main contributor(s) to the bundle size are.

Parcel does try to remove unused code from your bundle through scope hoisting and tree-shaking (see [docs](https://parceljs.org/features/scope-hoisting/)), but there are things that can mess up this process. You can get additional information about whether and why parcel might have had trouble here by adding the  `--log-level verbose` flag to your `parcel build` command.

Comment: Can you help me with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71509948/optimizing-images-using-parcel-2

Comment: Help me please.